# Exception encountered during startup: Unknown commitlog version 6

Tags: linux, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Cannot start cassandra in DataStax Enterprise (single node scenario)

runing `$ sudo service dse start` I get:

```
Starting DSE daemon : dse
DSE daemon starting with just Cassandra enabled (edit /etc/default/dse to enable)
```

running `$ nodetool status`

```
    Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199': Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

from output.log:

```
ERROR 08:03:24,900 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown commitlog version 6
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogDescriptor.getMessagingVersion(CommitLogDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:182)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:95)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:151)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:131)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:336)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:394)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.main(DseDaemon.java:574)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown commitlog version 6
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogDescriptor.getMessagingVersion(CommitLogDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:182)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:95)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:151)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:131)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:336)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:394)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.main(DseDaemon.java:574)
Exception encountered during startup: Unknown commitlog version 6
 INFO 08:03:24,915 DSE shutting down...
```

What can I do ? any suggestion are wellcome

Comment: Did you recently upgrade? What were the exact steps you followed when upgrading and what versions did you go from / to if you did?

Comment: just installed dse - v: 4.5.0, cassandra -v: 3.11.0

Comment: DSE4.5.x was aligned with Cassandra 2.0, see the release notes here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/RNdse45.html. Are you saying you moved up to Cass (Open Source) 3.11?

Comment: I've installed dse after cassandra installation

Comment: So you had Cassandra 3.11 running in place and then installed DSE4.5.0? Are those versions correct?